# useSWR returns correct data in the fetcher function but not in the main function

Tags: next.js

I'm using useSWR in my NextJS project but I'm having trouble with it returning undefined.

hooks.jsx

```
import useSWR from 'swr';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const fetcher = (url) => {
    fetch(url)
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .then((data) => {
            return { user: data?.user || null };
        });
};

function useUser({ redirectTo, redirectIfFound } = {} ) {
    const router = useRouter();

    const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/users/fetch', fetcher);
    const user = data?.user;
    const finished = Boolean(data);
    const hasUser = Boolean(user);

    console.log(user);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!redirectTo || !finished) return;

        if (
            // for register / signin route
            (redirectTo && redirectIfFound && hasUser)
        ) {
            router.push(redirectTo);
        }
    }, [redirectTo, redirectIfFound, finished, hasUser]);

    return error ? null : user;
}

export default useUser;
```

When I console logged the 'data' in the fetcher function, it returns the data as expected. However, in the main useUser function, the 'data' returns undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The fetch in your fetcher is not being returned.